# Optimal choice from 4 or 5 uniformly distributed random numbers with unknown range

Tags: algorithm, probability

Consider a hidden set of `k` random numbers `{r1,r2...rk}` chosen with uniform probability distribution from the range `[0..N]`, **where N is unknown to me**. In each time interval, the number `ri` is revealed to me and I have the choice of either choosing `ri` as my final number `c`, if I haven't already made a choice for `c`, or moving on to the next time interval. When `ri` is revealed to me I can no longer choose any of `r1,r2..r(i-1)`. If I haven't chosen a number by the time `rk` is revealed then, by default, that becomes `c`.

*I want to optimise c, in the sense maximizing its expected value.*

If `N` was known then the answer is obvious. Similarly, if `k` is large then I can use the early values of `ri` to estimate `N`.

Progress so far:

if `k = 1` then there is no choice. By default `c=r1`. The expected value of `c` is `N/2`.

if `k = 2` then all choice algorithms are identical with expected value `N/2`.

If `k = 3` then the best algorithm is

```
if r2/r1 >= 0.75 then 
  c=r2
else
  c=r3
```

The expected value of `c` is approximately `0.58N`.

If `k = 4` then the best I have come up with is

```
if r2/r1 > 0.920 then
  c=r2
elseif r3/r1 > 0.665 then
  c=r3
else
  c=r4
```

The expected value of `c` is approximately `0.64N`. I believe I should be able to do a little better by 'using' both the values of `r1` and `r2` in choosing if to accept `r3` as my chosen value but an analytical solution escapes me.

Can anyone provide a better algorithm for `k=4` and/or `k=5`?

**Notes re Secretary problem:**
In all versions of the SP i can find, you onl;y have information on the relative rank of candidates to those that have already appeared. But in this problem you have a value for each candidate (of course from an unknown range [0..N]) and by utilising the ratio of values you can do better. For example, the SP solution to the k=3 problem (choose p2 if p2 > p1 else choose p3) has an expected return of o.5833N, whereas my solution (choose p2 if p2/p1 > 0.75 else choose p3) has an expected return of 0.5937.

My best return so far for the problem for any k is:

```
 i = 0    
 repeat
    inc(i)
 until (r[i]/Max(r[1]..r[i-1]) > V[i]) or (i=k)
 c=r[i]
```

where for any chosen k, v[i] (or call it v[k,i] if you prefer) is a pre-chosen array of real values. The standard solutions to the secretary problem uses only values of inf and 1 in V V=[inf,...inf,1,...,1], whereas I can do better (at least for small k) by using reals in V. But I believe my solution is still sub-optimal as I utilize only the value of Max(r1..ri), whereas there must be 'hidden' information in the distribution of r1..ri values at each decision point.

Best solutions to date:

```
k = 3 : v = [inf,0.75]          : cexp = 0.58N
k = 4 : v = [inf,0.92,0.66]     : cexp = 0.665N
k = 5 : v = [inf,inf,0.82,0.63] : cexp = 0.6683N
```

Comment: Do you have any information about the probability distribution of *N* itself. I have the gut feeling that in order to properly solve the case for general *k*, you'll have to make some kind of assumption about the distribution of *N* as well.

Comment: In general I want a solution where N is completely unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a good reason for why the best solutions involve only comparing r<sub>i</sub> to Max(r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>, ..., r<sub>i</sub>): [the German Tank Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem).

Suppose you've just seen r<sub>k-1</sub>, the second-to-last number. Consider what your decision at that point is. You can either take r<sub>k-1</sub> or wait to see the yet unrevealed r<sub>k</sub>. When should you choose r<sub>k-1</sub>? When you think that r<sub>k-1</sub> is greater than the expected value of r<sub>k</sub> = N/2. But how can you estimate the expected value of r<sub>k</sub> if you don't know N? Well, what you would probably do is estimate N. And how do you do that? You use one of the solutions to the [German Tank Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) which relies only on the maximum (and count) of the observed values.

Working out the cases for r<sub>i</sub> where i < k-1 is less straightforward. For example, when you're looking at r<sub>k-2</sub>, you need to figure out what you'd do given that you have *two* more numbers to see and (potentially) one more choice to make. But, I suspect that in each case, the key thing you're doing is making some estimate of N, which involves only the maximum and count of the observed values so far.

Comment: Thanks, that reference was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

It is one of many modifications of 'Secretary problem' in optimal stopping theory. I don't have ready answer on your specyfic problem, but I highly recommend to read about this 'Secretary problem'. There is a lot papers about it and I sure you will find something for this.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can do better than `N/2` for `k=2`:

- take a guess at `N/2` and call it `m`.
- if `r1 > m` accept it as `c`, else reject and choose `r2` as `c`.

Here is the expectation of this strategy.

- if `m ≥ N`, then it always reject `r1` and accept `r2`, the  expected value of `c` is thus `N/2`.
- if `m < N`, then it accepts:

  - `r1` with probability `(N-m)/N`
  - `r2` with remaining probability probability `m/N`

In the second case the expectation of `r1` is `Σ_{m<i≤N} i / (N-m) > N/2`, while the expectation of `r2` is `N/2`. In this second case the expectation of the overall strategy is greater than `N/2`.

This strategy is better if you get a good guess of `N/2`, but the cute fact is that you can't get wrong: even if you're way off, the strategy at least yields `N/2` expectation.

Comment: I hadn't considered this, but doesn't this boil down to "pick a number smaller than the number I am thinking of".